# Why isn't an HTTP request being issued when the route changes?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember project with the following router:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/'}, function() {
    this.route('folder', {path: 'folder/:folder_id'});
  });
});

export default Router;
```

The contents of `routes/index/folder.js` are as follows:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    console.log(params);
    return this.store.query('message', {folder_id: params.folder_id});
  }
});
```

My expectation is that when the route changes to `/folder/1`, the `model()` method will be invoked to fetch the messages for the folder.

However, this does not occur. The route indeed changes, but the `model()` method is never invoked (nothing is written to the console).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess, you're using `{{#link-to 'index.folder' aModel}}` and since a model is already provided, there's no need to fetch it again. If you did `{{#link-to 'index.folder' aModel.id}}` it would trigger the `model` hook again because a model is not provided.

You can see in this [Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8d64757545288f4320d678b9bd2860c8?openFiles=routes.index.folder.js%2C&route=%2Ffolder%2F12) that the model hook is called in your example with visiting the path `folder/12` directly (not via link-to).

The [Routing Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/) goes into detail about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate the route using ember cli from the command line:
`ember g route folder`

It will create all the files that you need in the proper place, and also edit `router.js` accordingly.

This way I think you'll get a route that will answer to `/folder`. Then change `router.js`, adding the path for the route and hit `/folder/1`. If nothing happens check the console for errors, it can be that the `message` model doesn't exist.